# Actionscript 3.0(Adobe Flash CS4) Loading external .as files without knowing name of .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, module, flash-cs4

I want to know how to load external class files(.as files) in actionscript but don't have to know the class file's name. Think of it like loading mods in minecraft with forge mod loader, it doesn't know the main class of the mod's file name, yet it successfully loads the mod. I want to know if something like this is possible in actionscript 3.0 because I feel like making a tower defense game that isn't like the others out there but have it so it can be modded and have mods loaded but of course I have to load the class file without knowing the class file's name.
Note: I don't got access to Adobe Air so I can't use anything that requires Adobe Air.

Answer (score 0):

You want to load a particular .as file AFTER or BEFORE compilation? After the compilation it is hardly possible - the file would not be compiled and therefore it would be useless. Why don't you use a swf or some kind of XML/JSON with settings in that case? Before the compilation you would still need to identify it by it's package name/name.

Comment: Well what I'm asking is if there's a way to load class files without knowing the name of it or it's package system or if there's a way to detect a swf file without having to manually enter in the name of the swf file into the loader after compilation. Keep in mind, no adobe air.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want a plugin management system.
In AS3, it is not possible to "load" a .as file on execution, because it is a (uncompiled) source file. But, it is possible to load another swf and to use the classes within it.

Your process should probably be something like this :

- Get a list of the plugins/addons. If you were using AIR, it would have been possible by browsing the content of a folder. Since you're not, you'll probably need to use a listing file (basically, a file that say "Here's the list&path of the plugins you need to load".
- Load each swf file
- (possibly) call a initialization method for each plugin.

You may wish to look into the way OSMF manages plugins, for example : http://osmf.org/dev/osmf/OtherPDFs/osmf_plugin_dev_guide.pdf

Comment: I'll take look into it when I get more time to.